# Calculating cohesive blocks cohesion igraph 0.5.4

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a more or less direct way to estimate the cohesion for each cohesive block (i.e. the result of `cohesive.blocks()`) in igraph 0.5.4?

In the actual version (0.6) there is a function called `cohesion()`, but in version 0.5.x there is not. Is there an easier way to calculate it or should I just do it individually for each block (by hand!!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually in the documentation, even in the example:

```
g <- graph.disjoint.union(graph.full(4), graph.empty(2,directed=FALSE))
g <- add.edges(g,c(3,4,4,5,4,2))
g <- graph.disjoint.union(g,g,g)
g <- add.edges(g,c(0,6,1,7,0,12,4,0,4,1))

## Find cohesive blocks:
gBlocks <- cohesive.blocks(g)

## Examine block membership and cohesion:
gBlocks$blocks
# [[1]]
#  [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
# [[2]]
#  [1] 12 13 14 15 16
# [[3]]
#  [1]  0  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 10
# [[4]]
#  [1] 12 13 14 15
# [[5]]
#  [1] 0 1 2 3 4
# [[6]]
#  [1] 6 7 8 9

gBlocks$block.cohesion
# [1] 1 2 2 3 4 3
```

Comment: thanks,  I did not get it at the first try!, from there I can now calculate a cohesion integer for each `block`.!